# laravel query where not between is not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have to search halls for booking with given dates and time (morning and evening). How i can find available dates  from data with laravel query.
If i search dates 11-02-2019 to 27-02-2019 .It should only return 'These dates are not available!'. In this query it is returning booking 3. What's wrong with this query?
I have posted database image.

[image: database image]

```
public function getAvailableEvents(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $allInputs = Input::all();
        $categoryID = $request->input('category_id');
        $startDate = $request->input('start_date');
        $endDate = $request->input('end_date');
        $time = $request->input('time');

        $validation = Validator::make($allInputs, [
            'category_id' => 'required',
            'start_date' => 'required',
            'end_date' => 'required',
            'time' => 'required',
        ]);
        if ($validation->fails()) {
            DB::rollback();
            return $response = (new apiresponse())->customResponse('Fields required!',
                422,
                $validation->errors()->toArray());
        } else {

            $getEvents = Booking::where('category_id', '=', $categoryID)
            ->where('booking_time', '!=', $time)
            ->where('date_from', '!=', $startDate)
            ->where('date_to', '!=', $endDate)
            ->orWhere('date_from', '<', $startDate)
            ->orWhere('date_to', '>', $endDate)
            ->whereNotBetween('date_from', [$startDate,$endDate])
            ->whereNotBetween('date_to', [$startDate,$endDate])
            ->whereRaw("? NOT BETWEEN date_from AND date_to", [$startDate, $endDate])
            ->get();
           // dd($getEvents);

            if (count($getEvents) > 0) {
                $data = array();
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($getEvents); $i++) {
                    $data[] = array(

                        "booking_id" => $getEvents[$i]->id,
                        "ref_no" => $getEvents[$i]->ref_no,
                        "category_id" => $getEvents[$i]->category_id,
                        "event_id" => $getEvents[$i]->event_id,
                        "user_id" => $getEvents[$i]->user_id,
                        "phone" => $getEvents[$i]->phone,
                        "booking_status" => $getEvents[$i]->booking_status,
                        "type" => $getEvents[$i]->type,
                        "date_from" => $getEvents[$i]->date_from,
                        "date_to" => $getEvents[$i]->date_to,
                        "booking_time" => $getEvents[$i]->booking_time,
                        "price" => $getEvents[$i]->price,
                        "rating" => $getEvents[$i]->rating,
                        "date_time" => $getEvents[$i]->date_time ?? "",

                    );
                }
                return $response = (new apiresponse())->customResponse('Events found!',
                    200,
                    $data);

            } else {
                DB::rollback();
                return $response = (new apiresponse())->customResponse(
                    'These dates are not available!',
                    422,
                    (object)[]);
            }
        }

    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex) {
        return $response = (new apiresponse())->customResponse(
            'Fail!',
            422,
            $ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: What column type are your `date_from` and `date_to` fields?

Comment: using varchar for both

Comment: That's your problem, then. Use `DATE`, `DATETIME`, or `TIMESTAMP` fields for dates.

Comment: but with column type date .. this query is not showing any result. I'm always getting "These dates are not available"

Answer (score 3):

The less than / greater than comparisons aren't going to work reliably with a `varchar` data type on the date columns.

If you can, change the column type to `DATE` (or similar Date-specific type, whatever's appropriate for your application). Then the comparisons will work as expected.

If you can't, you can use the [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to convert to dates and then compare.

Comment: Good answer. I'd note that the `STR_TO_DATE` approach will be potentially very slow on large tables, as it must perform the conversion for every row in the table. Using proper date columns allows for proper indexing to be used.

Comment: I have changed and now with column type date .. this query is not showing any result. I'm always getting "These dates are not available".

Comment: Looking more closely at your code, you're likely also not quite querying the way you need to. You're creating a long list of `AND` and `OR` constraints on the query, but not grouping them in any way. So it's possible that if any constraint passes or doesn't pass properly, the result is being skewed. Try writing a raw SQL query that consistently returns the expected results, then translate that into Laravel.

Comment: I have to handle all scenarios in this query after changing type it is still showing incorrect results.